# How to detect when a user scrolls to the bottom of a div - Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm currently trying to implement infinite scrolling on my website, I'm using Vue Framework. There are a few infinite loading libraries for Vue but after integrating them, they had a few issues that were too major for me.

I already have it so I can add more data into an array once a certain condition is met, I just need to be able to detect when the bottom of a div is reached/scrolled down to.

I do need to integrate this with a for loop in Vue though which seems to not work with some common solutions. This is essentially what my code looks like.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div v-for="object in objects">
        <div class="class123">
            <p>Display Stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about detecting when a user scrolls down to the bottom of container?
I tried and it worked without Vue but once I add Vue in, it doesn't seem to work:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#container').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            alert('end reached');
        }
    })
});
```

I'd appreciate some help, thank you.

Comment: You are mixing two different frameworks together jQuery and Vue. There is plenty examples on internet how to implement infinite scroll only in Vue, like: https://medium.com/@rafaelogic/create-a-vuetiful-infinite-scroll-8913a069a201

Comment: I see, I didn't think it would be difficult to implement something small like that. I did end up getting vue-infinite-loading to work though, so thanks.

Comment: Don't mix vue and jquery as JQ manipulates the DOM directly and vue uses a virtual dom

Answer (score 24):

Credit to [Phan An](https://www.vuesnippets.com/posts/detect-user-scrolled-bottom/).

You have to catch the scroll event of the div itself and bind it to a method that calculates the scroll position and determines whether you scroll at the bottom. Using plain Vue:

```
<template>
  <div @scroll="onScroll"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default function () {
  methods: {
    onScroll ({ target: { scrollTop, clientHeight, scrollHeight }}) {
      if (scrollTop + clientHeight >= scrollHeight) {
        this.loadMorePosts()
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Working on the latest version of Chrome, Chromium Edge, and Firefox as of the posting date.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this NPM package `[Vue Infinite Scroll][1]` if you don't mind adding new dependency.

you can also see working example in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/fayazara/pen/PLmRLz

check this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@fayazara/easiest-way-to-implement-infinite-scroll-in-vue-js-54a0a6c1111) for more explanations

Comment: That's actually what I had started with but it seems nobody's updated the package in a couple years. There were a few bugs I encountered that quite a few people were complaining about. Thank you though.